# MySQL query select row with specific item

Tags: php, mysql

I have list of categories in my database that I populate in dropdown menu. The website should be able to display items depending on which category selected by user.

My current coding :

```
if ($selected_cat == "All Item" || !isset($selected_cat)) {
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct";
}
else {
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE prodCat = '$selected_cat'";
}
$result = $conn->query($sql_select);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($row);
        // some statement to display item
    }
}
```

So the problem here is, some of my `category's value` have **apostrophic (')** such as `Woman's Fashion`. If I run my query, mysql wouldn't be able to find the specific category as it read `Woman's Fashion` as **Woman\'s Fashion**, but my query `$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE prodCat = '$selected_cat'";` is reading it as **Woman's Fashion** which is wrong format in mysql.

Comment: Learn to use parameterized queries.  Avoiding unnecessary syntax errors is the best reason.  Avoiding SQL injection is a really close second.  Re-using query plans is a really close third.  And, there are no doubt other really good reasons too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope below code will help you use addslashes() function

```
if ($selected_cat == "All Item" || !isset($selected_cat)) {
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct";
}
else {
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE prodCat ='".addslashes($selected_cat)."'";
}
$result = $conn->query($sql_select);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        extract($row);
        // some statement to display item
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to prepare the queries then bind values to them in order to avoid this kind of issues. I have encountered this too many times because of the French speaking applications I have developed.

My best advise to you is merging toward PDO and using prepare + execute see the example below:

```
function getDocument($conn, $ref)
{
    $req = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM document where reference= :reference');
    $req->execute(array('reference' => $ref));
    return $req->fetchAll();
}
```

Believe me once you get used to PDO you'll save yourself from a lot of headaches of this kind. Furthermore, it will secure your app against SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using mysqli, learn to use bind parameterized prepared statements like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tblproduct WHERE prodCat = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

$stmt->bind_param("s", $selected_cat);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

You could do it the Object oriented way or your current procedural way Have a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php